# Counting the occurrences \ frequency of JSON element

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I have a project developed with Angular and I have a JSON file which I need to create objects(group by) by `ngFor` according to the `RaceName` field.
Meaning, I need to create one object for each `RaceName`.

```js
[
  {"Racename":"A1","Category":34,"Gender":"M","Work":"Amdocs","FullName":"Mark Owen"},
  {"Racename":"A1","Category":34,"Gender":"M","Work":"Amdocs","FullName":"Mark Owen"},
  {"Racename":"A2","Category":34,"Gender":"M","Work":"Amdocs","FullName":"Mark Owen"},
  {"Racename":"A3","Category":34,"Gender":"M","Work":"Amdocs","FullName":"Mark Owen"},
  {"Racename":"A4","Category":34,"Gender":"M","Work":"Amdocs","FullName":"Mark Owen"},
  {"Racename":"A5","Category":34,"Gender":"M","Work":"Amdocs","FullName":"Mark Owen"},
]
```

So, I'm expecting to have only 5 occurrences according to the attached JSON.

The HTML `div` tag is:
`<div class='table' *ngFor =  'let competition of filteredRaceName'>`
But I'm not sure what the `filteredRaceName` method should look like.

Comment: you can use `trackBY` in the ngFor to do this

Comment: not familiar with `trackBy`..I'll google it